# Dagger can't inject a Presenter in my Activities

Tags: android, dagger

I'm refactoring an Android app to an MVP architecture, using Dagger 1.

My code is more or less the following:

```
public interface View {
    Presenter getPresenter(); 
}

public abstract class Presenter {
    // Dagger 1 can't have an abstract class without injectable members... :(
    @Inject
    Application dont_need_this;

    protected View view;

    public void takeView(View view) { ... }
}
```

The field in `Presenter` is not pretty, but what can we do?

Next, I have an `Activity`  that's also a `View`.

```
public abstract class ActivityView extends Activity implements View {
    @Inject
    protected Presenter presenter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ObjectGraph scope;

        // Looks for an "scoped" ObjectGraph hold in an retained fragment

        if (/* fragment is null */) {
            // This is not a rotation but the first time the activity is 
            // launched

            MVPApplication app = (MVPApplication) getApplication();
            ObjectGraph scope = app.createScope(this);

            // Store in the fragment
         }

         scope.inject(this);

         // setContentView, etc.

         presenter.takeView(this);
    }

}
```

All seems good for now...

```
public abstract class MVPApplication extends Application {

        private ObjectGraph objectGraph;

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();

            // Root scope
            // createRootModules is defined in the subclass
            objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(createRootModules()); 
            objectGraph.inject(this);
         }

         public abstract ObjectGraph createScope(View view);
 }
```

With this, my application subclass has to:

- define `createRootModules()` to instantiate every module in the root scope
- check in `createScope()` the class of the concrete ActivityView, essentially using a `HashMap<Class<? extends View>, Module>` and do...

`return objectGraph.plus(new ModuleForThisActivityViewClass());`

For example, I have an `CollectionActivityView`. My app tries to...

```
return objectGraph.plus(new CollectionModule());
```

And I have the binding for this particular `Presenter` in this module:

```
@Module(addsTo = MyAppModule.class,
    injects = {CollectionActivityView.class, CollectionPresenter.class}, complete=false)
public class CollectionModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public Presenter providePresenter(CollectionPresenter presenter) {
        return presenter;
    }
}
```

**But** when doing the 'plus()` this error happens:

```
ComponentInfo{com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.view.CollectionActivityView}:      
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create binding for 
    com.mycompany.myapp.mvp.presenter.Presenter

...

 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create binding for 
    com.mycompany.myapp.mvp.presenter.Presenter
        at dagger.internal.Linker.linkRequested(Linker.java:147)
        at dagger.internal.Linker.linkAll(Linker.java:109)
        at dagger.ObjectGraph$DaggerObjectGraph.linkEverything(ObjectGraph.java:244)
        at dagger.ObjectGraph$DaggerObjectGraph.plus(ObjectGraph.java:203)
```

Dagger is trying to resolve the dangling dependency of the superclass `Presenter` in `ActivityView` **before** plusing the ObjectGraph with the new Module, who is in charge of providing the Presenter.

Is there a way to avoid this? Am I doing something terribly wrong? Do you have any suggestions for doing this properly?

Comment: If you are using `plus()` you need to add `addsTo()` on the @Module that you are plussing. If I undertand correctly in your case it would be. `@Module{..., addsTo = ModuleForThisActivityViewClass.class, ...}`

Comment: I don't think so, the addsTo goes in the module that *is* plussing, doesn't it?

Comment: It is hard to explain with words, but yes. `addsTo` goes on the @Module that you are plus()sing. And the plus()ed Module is the top most module at that time on the `ObjectGraph` if you want to have its dependencies. Does that make sense? lol.

Comment: Yes, of course. :D `CollectionModule` `addsTo` `MyAppModule` indeed, so I **think** that's covered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at it again, it was my fault.

I don't know why I did it (probably trying to avoid tagging the module as incomplete or library) but `MyAppModule` declared it was injecting `CollectionActivityView`, so the `Presenter` dependency had to be resolved in that module before *plussing* the other. Removed that from the annotation in `MyAppModule` and everything worked as intended.